# Select related many-to-many field in Django in model

Tags: django

I have the following classes in my model:

```
class Dish(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

  def get_ingredients(self): 
    return #what to return?

class DishIngredient(models.Model):
  dish          = models.ForeignKey(Dish, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
  ingredient = models.ForeignKey(Ingredient, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
  number_of_units  = models.IntegerField('number of units')

class Ingredient(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  unit = models.ForeignKey(Unit, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

I want Dish.get_ingredients() to return a sequence of DishIngredient.number_of_units, Ingredient.name, Ingredient.unit

Anybody know how to do this?

Comment: Just an update: I learned that my model could be better. I could largely avoid the problem by adding ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient, through='DishIngredient') to my Dish model.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Dish(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    @property
    def get_ingredients(self):
         data = []
         dish_ingredients = DishIngredient.objects.filter(dish=self)
         for di in dish_ingredients:
            item = {
                    'number_of_units': di.number_of_units,
                    'name': di.ingredient.name,
                    'unit': di.ingredient.unit
                 }        
            data.append(item)
         return data
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!